# Problem with jQuery

Tags: jquery, input, append, prepend, insertafter

```
if ( !this.labelContainer.append(label).length )
 this.settings.errorPlacement
  ? this.settings.errorPlacement(label, $(element) )
  : label.insertAfter(element);
```

(this code is from validate plugin, it repeats for each input)

`label` is `<label>text</label>`

`element` is `<input />`

This works good, it adds `label` directly after the `element`.

Looks like this:

```
<dd>
    <div>
        <input />
        <label>text</label>
    </div>
</dd>
```

**How to place `label` after the `<div>` (`element`'s parent), not after the `element`?**

Full code of the script:

http://www.jsfiddle.net/YSSCE/1/ (search for `label.insertAfter(element)`)

Comment: `label.insertAfter(element);` into `label.insertAfter(div);` where `div` is the identifier of the `div` you want to insert after.

Comment: woo... I just love the expression " _doesn't work_ " ! That makes things go faster and more clear !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`insertAfter`](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/). **[Example on jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/brunolm/YC6z3/)**

```
$("<label />").text("Label").insertAfter(
    $("input").parent()
);
```

---

[Updating your code (v2)](http://www.jsfiddle.net/brunolm/YSSCE/2/):

```
this.settings.errorPlacement
      /* not sure what this method do, maybe you need to add .parent() as well*/
    ? this.settings.errorPlacement(label, $(element) )
    : label.insertAfter($(element).parent()); /* insert after the parent */
```

Comment: Can you update your solution to my code? Here is a full file http://www.jsfiddle.net/YSSCE/1/

Answer (score 0):

element.parent gets the parent to the element.

```
label.insertAfter(element.parent);
```

or possibly

```
label.insertAfter($(element).parent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change label.insertAfter(element) to label.insertAfter(element.parent())

But this could cause problems if your HTML markup changes.

Comment: It was assuming the element is a jQuery object. This should have been assumed as the parent() function is a jQuery function.